# How to manage many items having the same route?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have an angular 6 application, the navigation menu is dynamically created from a Rest Api. When you click on an item, you go `to home/item` but there are too many items in the menu, so I cannot write all the logic in `home.ts`

And I cannot create components from the cli because each time you add an item to the rest api, it should be added to the menu, and each time you remove an item from the api, it should be removed. each item is totally different than the other, different page design, different content.

How to manage such scenario? either dynamically creating items or writing a code that would be readable even  if you have 100 items.

Comment: If my question should be closed, kindly tell me why, so that at least I get an answer on how to solve the problem I have

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loading ? (it's only one idea)